# align multiple figures with `fig.align`

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I have multiple figures that are output from a single code chunk. The goal is to have them appear next to each other, centered on the page. So far, I have been unable to make this happen. There is a rendered version of these examples [here](https://bd-reprex.netlify.app/align-multiple-figures-with-fig-align.html#align-multiple-figures-with-fig.align), which comes from [this source document](https://github.com/wjakethompson/bd-reprex/blob/master/03-method.Rmd).

This first chunk places two images side-by-side and left-aligned on the page. The code results in 2 `<img>` tags without anything special, other than the specified width.

````r
```{r test1, out.width='32.8%', fig.show='hold'}
knitr::include_graphics(rep('images/knit-logo.png', 2))
```
````

```html
<img src="images/knit-logo.png" width="32.8%" />
<img src="images/knit-logo.png" width="32.8%" />
```

Now say I want the figures centered. So perhaps I try setting `fig.align='center'`. This center aligns the figures, but now they are no longer side-by-side. In the HTML output, we see that `style="display: block; margin: auto;"` has been added to the `<img>` tag.

````r
```{r test2, out.width='32.8%', fig.show='hold', fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics(rep('images/knit-logo.png', 2))
```
````

```html
<img src="images/knit-logo.png" width="32.8%" style="display: block; margin: auto;" />
<img src="images/knit-logo.png" width="32.8%" style="display: block; margin: auto;" />
```

Now if I add a figure caption, the images are side-by-side again and centered. In the HTML, we can see that using a `fig.cap` places the images inside a `<div>`. The `div` is centered, but there is no "block" display that keeps the images from appearing on the same line.

````r
```{r test3, out.width='32.8%', fig.show='hold', fig.align='center', fig.cap='A test caption.'}
knitr::include_graphics(rep('images/knit-logo.png', 2))
```
````

```html
<div class="figure" style="text-align: center">
  <img src="images/knit-logo.png" alt="A test caption." width="32.8%" />
  <img src="images/knit-logo.png" alt="A test caption." width="32.8%" />
  <p class="caption">(\#fig:test3-display)A test caption.</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to place multiple figures into a `<div class="figure" style="text-align: center">` without specifying a figure caption? It seems like there should be a way to do this, but I haven't found any solutions so far. Ultimately the goal is to have the third set of output (rendered version [here](https://bd-reprex.netlify.app/align-multiple-figures-with-fig-align.html#align-multiple-figures-with-fig.align)) but without the caption.

In addition to the linked GitHub repo and rendered site, here's a minimal standalone Rmd file that replicates the issue:

````
---
title: "Align multiple figures with `fig.align`"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

I have multiple figures that are output from a single code chunk. The goal is to
have them appear next to each other, centered on the page. So far, I have been
unable to make this happen. Here are some examples:

This first chunk places two images side-by-side and left-aligned on the page.
The code results in 2 `<img>` tags without anything special, other than the
specified width.

```{r test1, out.width='32.8%', fig.show='hold'}
knitr::include_graphics(rep('https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/images/knit-logo.png', 2))
```

Now say I want the figures centered. So perhaps I try setting
`fig.align='center'`. This center aligns the figures, but now they are no longer
side-by-side. In the HTML output, we see that
`style="display: block; margin: auto;"` has been added to the `<img>` tag.

```{r test2, out.width='32.8%', fig.show='hold', fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics(rep('https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/images/knit-logo.png', 2))
```

Now if I add a figure caption, the images are side-by-side again and centered.
In the HTML, we can see that using a `fig.cap` places the images inside a
`<div>`. The `div` is centered, but there is no "block" display that keeps the
images from appearing on the same line.

```{r test3, out.width='32.8%', fig.show='hold', fig.align='center', fig.cap='A test caption.'}
knitr::include_graphics(rep('https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/images/knit-logo.png', 2))
```
````

Comment: See https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/index.html

Comment: @Michael I've looked at patchwork, but unfortunately that only works for combining ggplot2 objects, and won't work for pre-existing images, as in my example.

Comment: Ah, I skimmed too quickly. Good luck!

Comment: I guess you can get this using a custom hook. However, if you don't mind the whitespace resulting from the non-zero bottom margin of the `<p>` element you could use an empty caption, i.e., set `fig.cap=' '` in chunk `test3`.

Comment: @M.A. Ah! Yes, this does it. I had tried `fig.cap=''`, with no spaces. But that had the same effect as no caption. Using `fig.cap=' '`, with spaces, put the figures into the `<div>` tag. If you want to submit this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

knitr does not center the images on the same line if you omit the chunk option `fig.cap` in chunk `test3`, i.e., the CSS attribute `text-align: center` of the enclosing `<div>` element is missing in the final HTML output.

A remedy is to add `fig.cap = ' '` (*must be a blank, not an empty string!*). Note that this also adds an empty `<p>` element (for the caption) below the images which results in some additional whitespace.